# calculating sum of an irregular time interval data in R

Tags: r, time, merge, sum, intervals

I have two dataframe: dataframe 1, which is a irregular time interval data with categorical values, and dataframe 2, which is a regular interval data with integer values.

**Dataframe 1**

| Start Date | End Date | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1980-01-05 | 1983-02-17 | A |
| 1983-02-17 | 1987-01-02 | B |
| 1987-01-02 | 1989-11-10 | C |
| 1989-11-10 | 1992-03-20 | D |

**Dataframe 2**

| Date | variable 1 | variable 2 | variable 3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1980-01-01 | 0 | 0 | 2 | ... |
| 1980-02-01 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... |
| 1980-03-01 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... |
| 1980-04-01 | 0 | 1 | 2 | ... |
| 1980-05-01 | 0 | 1 | 0 | ... |
| 1980-06-01 | -1 | 0 | 1 | ... |
| 1980-07-01 | -2 | 0 | 1 | ... |
| 1980-08-01 | -1 | 0 | 2 | ... |
| 1980-09-01 | 0 | 2 | 1 | ... |
| 1980-10-01 | 0 | 0 | 2 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Using this dataframe, I would like to merge the observations from dataframe 2 into dataframe 1, adding up the values that fall into the interval of Start date to End Date in dataframe 1.

so the output should look something like:

| Start Date | End Date | Category | variable 1 | variable 2 | variable 3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1980-01-05 | 1983-02-17 | A | Sum of variable 1 from the start date to end date | Sum of variable 2 from the start date to end date | Sum of variable 3 from the start date to end date | ... |
| 1983-02-17 | 1987-01-02 | B | Sum of variable 1 from the start date to end date | Sum of variable 2 from the start date to end date | Sum of variable 3 from the start date to end date | ... |
| 1987-01-02 | 1989-11-10 | C | Sum of variable 1 from the start date to end date | Sum of variable 2 from the start date to end date | Sum of variable 3 from the start date to end date | ... |
| 1989-11-10 | 1992-03-20 | D | Sum of variable 1 from the start date to end date | Sum of variable 2 from the start date to end date | Sum of variable 3 from the start date to end date | ... |

Comment: Is it always guaranteed that End Date row n = Start Date row n+1?

Comment: Yes. It is always guaranteed so.  @dash2

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using my santoku package. You could also use `cut.Date`.

```r
library(santoku)
library(dplyr)

# I assume that df1$Start_Date is a Date object
start_dates <- df1$Start_Date
df2$Start_Date <- santoku::chop(df2$Date, start_dates, labels = lbl_endpoint())
df2$Start_Date <- as.Date(as.character(df2$Start_Date))

df_summ <- df2 %>% 
             left_join(df1,  by = "Start_Date") %>%
             group_by(Start_Date) %>%
             summarize(
               End_Date   = End_Date[1],
               Category   = Category[1],
               Variable_1 = sum(Variable_1),
               Variable_2 = sum(Variable_2),
               Variable_3 = sum(Variable_3)
             )
```

You could also use `across()` for variables 1 to 3, but the above is very simple and clear at the cost of some repetition.